# VBA solver compilation error

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I get a compilation error (sub for function not defined) while executing this VBA solver code:

```
Sub Macro1()
SolverReset
SolverOk SetCell:="$H$6", _
MaxMinVal:=2, _
ValueOf:="0", _
ByChange:="$H$15:$H$20"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$H$15:$H$20", Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$H$15:$H$20", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$H$9", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="$I$9"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$H$10", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="$I$10"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$H$24", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$I$24"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$H$25", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$I$25"
SolverSolve userFinish:=True
End Sub
```

Am I missing anything here in the code?

Comment: At which line, it shows error?

Comment: It looks like you're missing a reference , try adding a solver add-in reference from Tools - > References...

Comment: Thanks Imran...I missed that part...it solves the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to activate the solver add-in.

Look here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/using-the-solver-vba-functions